# why the properties are not working properly

Tags: python

I have a problem with my program, namely after entering a letter in input, the program crashes. The task says that I have to control whether the data is correct with the help of properties. However, as if the program does not go there at all.I know that casting on int it will always go through the property and throw out when counting, but when it does not project it will throw the program anyway. Please help. Here is my code:

```
 import math


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):

        if not isinstance(x, int):
            raise TypeError(f"{x} is not INT")
        self._x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        if not isinstance(y, int):
            raise TypeError(f"{y} is not INT")
        self._y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "coordinate x: {0.x}\tcoordinate y: {0.y}".format(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(x:{self.x},y:{self.y})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__.__name__ == other.__class__.__name__:
            return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
        raise TypeError("Is not object of class Point")

    def distance_from_origin(self, x, y):
        odl = math.sqrt((0 - x) ** 2 + (0 - y) ** 2)
        return odl


class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError('radius must be > 0')
        self._radius = radius

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(x:{self.x},y:{self.y},promień:{self.radius})"

    def __str__(self):
        return "coordinate circle x: {0.x}\tcoordinate circle y: {0.y}\tcircle radius: {0.radius}".format(self)

    def area(self):
        pole = (math.pi * (self.radius ** 2))
        return pole

    def circumference(self):
        obw = 2 * math.pi * self.radius
        return obw

    def edge_distance_from_origin(self):
        odl = math.sqrt((0 - self.x) ** 2 + (0 - self.y) ** 2)
        brzeg = odl - self.radius
        return brzeg

    def __eq__(self, other):
        super().__eq__(other)
        if self.__class__.__name__ == other.__class__.__name__:
            return self.radius == other.radius
        raise TypeError("is not object of class Circle")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input("enter the coordinate x: "))
    y = int(input("enter the coordinate y: "))
    p1 = Point(x, y)
    p2 = Point(5, 7)

    c1 = Circle(5, 5, 5)
    c2 = Circle(3, 3, 5)
    print(p1)  # str
    print(repr(p1))  # repr
    print(c1)
    print(repr(c1))
    print("Distance from the center of the coordinate axes:", round(p1.distance_from_origin(x, y), 2))
    print(p1 == p2)
    print(round(c1.area(), 2))
    print("Distance of the edge of the circle from the center of the coordinate axis:", round(c1.edge_distance_from_origin(), 2))
    print(c1 == c2)
```

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):

        if not isinstance(x, int):
            raise TypeError(f"{x} is not INT")
        self.x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        if not isinstance(y, int):
            raise TypeError(f"{y} is not INT")
        self.y = y
```

Comment: Because the attributes have the same names.

Comment: no they don't and not in the name is problem. the problem is in inputs..

Comment: Look, you have a property `x`. It's a class attribute meaning it is attached to the class. Now if you do the `self.x = …`, am instance attribute will be created. It will shadow the property on the class.

Comment: You have an error in this line: `print("Distance from the center of the coordinate axes:", round(p1.distance_from_origin(x, y), 2))`:  _x_ and _y_ are undefined

Comment: @Klaus D. i need to change name of the class atributes???

Comment: Michael Rovinsky but its working and compiler saying nothing about it

Comment: You have to bring your names in order. The typical way would be to use `x` for the property and `_x` for the instance attribute storing the value. And Python is not a compiled language.

Comment: look at the edit code. did i changed names good?